# Use std::array in function using 'overloaded' lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, stdarray

I wish to do the following in C++20:

```cpp
template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator( )...;
};

// Updated to work with C++17
#if (_cplusplus != 202002L)    // check for C++17 or C++20
// Deduction guide, google `CTAD for aggregates` for more info
template <typename... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;    // not needed before C++20
#endif

template <typename T, long int C = 0>
void emit(T const& data) {

    auto emit = overloaded {

        [&](const auto& value) {
            mOs << value;
        },
        [&](const uint8_t& value) {
            mOs << std::showbase << (uint16_t)value;
        },
        [&](const std::array<T, C>& value) {
           for (auto& v : value) { // error: can't increment 0 size std::array
               mOs << v;
           }
        },
        // bunch more lambdas
    };
    emit(data);
}

// invoked by
emit(1);
```

How can the std::array be captured since the count is required?

Without setting C to zero all the other lambdas fail.

May not be possible but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the lambdas template parameter list introduced in C++20. The lambdas  argument is not a `std::array<T,C>` but it is `T`, and `T` is some `std::array<S,C>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator( )...;
};

template <typename T>
void emit(T const& data) {
    std::ostream& mOs = std::cout;

    auto emit = overloaded {
        [&](const auto& value) {
            mOs << value;
        },
        [&](const uint8_t& value) {
            mOs << std::showbase << (uint16_t)value;
        },
        [&]<typename S,size_t C>(const std::array<S, C>& value) {
           for (auto& v : value) { 
               mOs << v;
           }
        },
        // bunch more lambdas
    };
    emit(data);
}
int main(){
    // invoked by
    std::array<int,42> x;
    emit(x);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aT6zPjn1x)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. That works well. Also addressed how to handle vector which was my next task. 

This also works with C++17 in GCC 11.

Comment: @rm1948 Lambda template parameters were introduced in C++20. If it's working with GCC 11 under C++17 mode, then that's a GCC extension. You should consider enabling `-pedantic` so that the compiler [can warn you of such cases](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbj6nnbWj)

Comment: @Human-Compiler - You are correct. It is an extension of GCC. It works back to GCC 7.1 and Clang 9.0, Just information...